# In what countries are royalties from a patent beyond 20 years still allowed

Tags: licensing, royalty, license, royalties

I heard that in the US, the inventor can no longer collect royalties beyond 20 years for their patent.

In what other countries is royalties beyond 20 years still allowed?

Comment: I think the question is slightly off the mark. I’m not a lawyer, but you could license a patent to someone for beyond its expiration. Maybe in return for a lower royalty per year. What the law allows you to do is sue for infringement while the patent is active. What I think you are asking is whether there are countries where the patent terms are longer than 20 years.

Comment: @Eric - actually a SCOTUS case determined that a royalty can not be paid after expiration in the US. It is a rare limit on the ability to contract. It is against public policy to effectively extend a patent beyond its term. I mentioned this in an answer somewhere recently. However, I believe you might get a fee for trade secret “know-how”. https://supreme.justia.com/cases/federal/us/379/29/

Comment: @GeorgeWhite Interesting. I still think the OP is asking if there are countries where the patent term is beyond 20 years. In the cited case and in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kimble_v._Marvel_Entertainment,_LLC the contracts had no end. It would be different if, for instance, one had a fixed royalty and negotiated a longer but fixed term to pay it. Especially since it wouldn't keep anyone else from practicing the invention once the patent expired.

Comment: @GeorgeWhite is right. I am asking if the law in other countries enforce licensing deals where the royalty is beyond 20 years.

Comment: @EricS - there was some dicta about the illogic of the previous ruling but in the end from Wikipedia: “ The Supreme Court affirmed the judgment below, 6-3, largely on stare decisis grounds, but in the course of its ruling the Court explained why the Brulotte decision was correct and its critics wrong, as to the substantive law.”

Comment: OP - it is very unlikely you will get a good answer here. You might try Law. Also it is a licensing question and is off topic.

Comment: @EricS - I have seen articles from law firms that say call us and we can work around it. So I agree there are likely ways to solve the problem assuming the licensee sees a win in it for them. I have negotiated several royalty deals with no patent at all involved.